# Local mailbox delivery for non local recipients with exim for demo server

Tags: exim

I have used the following router and transport with exim < 4.94 to deliver all mail non local mail to a mailbox file instead of actually sending it. This is for a demo server to test an application. The mailbox files are processed to provide a web view of them.

The router:

```
nonlocal:
  debug_print = "R: nonlocal for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = accept
  domains = ! +local_domains
  transport = demo_spool
  no_more
```

The transport:

```
demo_spool:
  debug_print = "T: appendfile for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = appendfile
  file = /var/mail/remote/${tr{$local_part@$domain}{.}{_}}
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add
  return_path_add
  group = mail
  mode = 0660
  mode_fail_narrower = false
```

This stopped working with exim 4.94, because it rightfully considers `$local_part` (and most likely `$domain`) as tainted (which would allow an attacker to control the filename).

I don't fully understand the flow of `$local_part_data`. The default acl checks set it when local_parts is checked, but I can't get it to end up in the transport. For the `localuser` router and `local_delivery` transport it works and I don't know why.

The problem I have is that I can't get `$local_part_data` to be set correctly as a replacement. I can't do a lookup, because the email addresses used are arbitrary. I don't really worry about an attacker, because the demo server is restricted to a few people in the company. I guess a relatively simple check to prevent invalid characters and something like `..` to prevent file directory escape would be enough for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the strict rules about tainted variables in exim 4.94 this has broken a lot of config files.

In the router section of the config, $local_part_data only gets set if you have the config option **check_local_user** (in cases of local users as supported by the OS) or by setting the value of the option **local_parts**.  It seems anything stuck into $local_part_data during ACL is discarded once the router section is processed.

If you are *absolutely* certain that you wish to use the value of $local_part despite any risks involved, you can "de-taint" the value by putting this line into your router config (assuming UNIX OS):

```
local_parts = ${run{/bin/echo $local_part}{$value}}
```

Now your $local_part_data is set for the transport section.  If you are wanting to make this more secure, you could instead run a script that sanitizes the value passed in from exim.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!